# How to finish the current activity and start another one?

Tags: android, android-activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
/**
     * Check for login session. If not logged in launch
     * login activity
     * */
    if (MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser() == null) {
        launchLoginActivity();
        Log.e(TAG, "Still im in MainActivity !!! ");
    }
 ....
 ....
```

and this is the launch activity method:

```
 private void launchLoginActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    Log.e(TAG, "launchLoginActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

The activity is launched but I still am in my main activity.

As you can see in the console, the two log messages are displayed.

One in launch method, and another one in the main activity after the launch method is called.

**How can I finish my main activity and not display the log message in the main activity?**

[image: The error]

Comment: check activity Lifecycle  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: Are you try with flag ``intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
`` and remove ``finish();`` function

Answer (score 2):

Your main activity will, eventually, finish after you exit from `onCreate()`. Put some debug logging in your main activity's `onDestroy()` and you will see you get in there.
If you want to skip everything after invoking your second activity then just put a `return` after that.
There is also the `Activity.isFinishing()` API which returns true if your activity is being finished.

Answer (score -1):

Well, finish() the activity in question and then return so that the starting activity breaks out of the 'onCreate' method and the acitvity is destroyed through the normal live cycle.

```
if (MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser() == null) {
    launchLoginActivity(); //the finish part already happens here. I did not see that.
    return;
    Log.e(TAG, "Still im in MainActivity !!! ");
}
```

Comment: The submitter does that

Comment: Whops, seems that I didn't see that line. Thats what you get for starting the day without a coffee :(.  So yeah, the previous authors are right, add the return after the method call.